# Weird regular expression behavior in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why RegExp with global flag in Javascript give wrong results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results)

My code is as follows,

HTML:

```
<p id="test"></p>​
```

JavaScript:

```
var patt = /h/gi;
var arr = ["", "2Hour", "4Hour", "8Hour", "Next Business Day"];
var test = document.getElementById("test");

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    if (patt.test(arr[i])) {
        test.innerHTML += " " + arr[i];
    }
}
```

However, the output that  get is `2Hour 8Hour`, why's 4Hour not a part of the output?

Is there something wrong with my regex? how can I solve this issue?

I've put it up on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QbXEX/6/)

​

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To quote MDN:

> As with exec (or in combination with it), test called multiple times
>   on the **same global regular expression instance** will advance past the
>   previous match.

Currently what is happening is:

1. the regular expression stored in `patt` tests the second string, finds a match at the index `1`, and retains this information
2. The next time you use `test` it tries to find a match from index `1`
   *onwards*, which obviously yields no match, since it is effectively testing the string `"our"`
3. This resets the pointer to `0`, allowing the match in the next
   string at index `1` to be found.

So to solve your problem, simply create a new instance on each iteration:

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    if (/h/gi.test(arr[i])) {
        test.innerHTML += " " + arr[i];
    }
}
```

This "clears the pointer" as it were, and ensures that the regex behaves identically for each string it is tested against.

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/QbXEX/12/